# Does Odo retain his humanoid senses when regaining his morphing abilities?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

When Odo became human he gained the ability to enjoy food in a way he could not as a changeling. When he was reverted to a changeling did he retain his sense of taste/ smell?

Comment: Why would he? Changelings cannot taste or smell, so "reverted" Odo shouldn't be expected to, either.

Comment: On the other hand, why wouldn't he? He was given the ability to taste and smell. Why would this stop when he regains his shapeshifting abilities?   And do we know for sure that other changelings can't taste? Maybe  Odo was unique in the disability.

Answer (score 3):

The series doesn't mention whether Odo had a sense of smell after his solid period, but my guess is that he did not.

When Odo was made solid in S04E26, Bashir noted that he had human internal organs - something he hadn't had as a changeling. [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/274710/117563) to a related question points out that some changelings could duplicate human anatomy perfectly: the humans couldn't find *any* difference, so presumably they managed a working olfactory system. This required a level of shapeshifting skill that Odo wasn't shown to achieve in the series.

Having experienced taste and smell himself might have increased Odo's understanding of their mechanisms, and he might have had more desire to learn to make his nose work so he could continue enjoying the smells around him. (Or he might not - do we know what Kira's breath was like in the morning?)

On the other hand, Odo had other things to think about, and even if he made perfect smell receptors it is not guaranteed that he would be able to experience smell through them in the same way he had as a solid. On balance, it seems more likely that he simply went back to his old life and didn't smell again, at least for the rest of the series.